# Append the next line to previous line

Tags: python

I have file of 5GB in this format:

```
dn: cn
changetype: add
objectclass: ine
hghsfgdsdsdsd
mail: surcom
surname: satya2
givenname: surya2
cn: surya2
```

```
dn: cn
changetype: add
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
surname: sa
sddsds
givenname: s
cn: sur
```

as you can see the Object class and surname are getting to the next line.
I want then in same line.
And below code achieves it, but it throws memory error for large files,
can you change this code so that it works efficiently for large files.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+):(.*)")

with open("uservolvo2.ldif", "r") as f:
    new_lines = []

    for line in f:

        if line.endswith('\n'):
            line = line[:-1]

        if line == "":
            new_lines.append(line)
            continue    

        l = pattern.search(line)

        if l:
            new_lines.append(line)
        else:
            new_lines[-1] += line

with open("user_modified.ldif", "a") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(new_lines))
    f.write("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of writing a big string, when you join `new_lines`, which might be causing the memory error, you can iterate over the list and write each line one by one

```
with open("file_modified.txt", "a") as f:
    for line in new_lines:
        f.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: Can you try with a smaller file, also how are you running the code?

Comment: it works alright for small files. i am running it in linux os

Comment: From the interpreter, or an IDE like PyCharm?

Comment: interpreter, no ide

Comment: check if this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435577/memory-error-python-processing-large-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient a regex-based solution would be, nor have I benchmarked it, but here is one possible approach using `re.sub` on the entire file:

```
input = """objectclass: ine
hghsfgdsdsdsd
mail: surcom
surname: satya2"""

output = re.sub(r'objectclass:(\s*\S+)(.*?)surname:(\s*\S+)',
                "objectclass:\\1\nsurname:\\3\\2", input, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
objectclass: ine
surname: satya2
hghsfgdsdsdsd
mail: surcom
```

The above logic is to match an `objectclass:` line, followed by all content until reaching the `surname:` line.  Then, we piece back together the text in the order you want it, with `surname` immediately following `objectclass`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the most efficient way is to create another empty text file (`modified.txt`), `iter` through the original text file and append processed line to the new file.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file, open('modified.txt', 'a') as modified:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        line = file.readline()
        #do procssing
        modified.write(line)
```